# C++ Visual Studio Error: IntelliSense: expected a statement

Tags: c++

```
while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT)) //VK_INSERT = Insert key on numpad
{

    if (clock() - GameAvailTMR > 100)
    {
        GameAvailTMR = clock();
        IsGameAvail = false;

        hGameWindow = FindWindow(NULL, LGameWindow);
        if (hGameWindow)
        {
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hGameWindow, &dwProcID);
            if (dwProcID != 0)
            {
                hProcHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcID);
                if (hProcHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hProcHandle == NULL);
                {
                    GameStatus = "Faild to open process for value handle";
                }
                else
                {
                    GameStatus = "AssaultCube Ready To Hack";
                    IsGameAvail = true;
                }


            }
        }
    }

}
```

On my visual studio IDE the else statement is underlined red and the error "IntelliSense: expected a statement" pops up. I'm on Visual Studio 2013 if that matters.

Comment: You need to take the `;` off the end of the line `if ( hProcHandle`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the semicolon off this line:

```
if (hProcHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || ...);
```

It's terminating the `if` statement so that there's a valid block afterwards (which would execute regarless of the `if` statement):

```
{
    // some valid statements
}
```

followed by a very *invalid,* "naked" `else`.